# How to correctly display text inside a JavaScript alert when using backticks?

Tags: javascript

I remarked that alert messages are not displayed correctly when I use backticks:

[image]

Example:

```js
var classicMsg = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting "
      + "ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy "
      + "text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley "
      + "of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
var backticksMsg = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
                    ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy 
                    text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley 
                    of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`;

document.getElementById("btnAlert1").addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(classicMsg);
});

document.getElementById("btnAlert2").addEventListener('click', function(){
 alert(backticksMsg);
});
```

```css
li{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="btnAlert1">Test with classic message</li>
  <li id="btnAlert2">Test with backticks message</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a better way to correctly display alert backticks texts than writing a custom function to do that?... I mean without doing something like this:

```
function formatTextBeforeCallingAlert(txt) {
    return txt.replace(/\n/g, '').replace(/\t/g, '');
}
```

Comment: "Any new line characters inserted in the source are part of the template literal." - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) - so unless you want a newline, don't add a newline.

Comment: @gerrit0 But I don't want to lose the advantage of using "interpolation" to insert the content of variables...

Comment: why does removing new lines prevent interpolation?

Comment: No, I mean when having a long text I prefer to use the template literal

Comment: Then that's what output is...the literal template including any extra spaces or new lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that backticks mean **literal**, so all those extra spaces are added to the result. You can either remove those spaces or use some other form, like quotes + \ to use multilines.

```js
var classicMsg = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting "
      + "ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy "
      + "text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley "
      + "of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";
var backticksMsg = `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`;

var breaklineMsg = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing\
and typesetting ndustry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard\
dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley\
of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.";

document.getElementById("btnAlert1").addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert(classicMsg);
});

document.getElementById("btnAlert2").addEventListener('click', function(){
 alert(backticksMsg);
});

document.getElementById("btnAlert3").addEventListener('click', function(){
 alert(breaklineMsg);
});
```

```css
li{cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="btnAlert1">Test with classic message</li>
  <li id="btnAlert2">Test with backticks message</li>
  <li id="btnAlert2">Test with breakline \ message</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only a slightly cleaner way of using your `formatTextBeforeCallingAlert`function.

You can use a tagged template literal in order to remove unwanted whitespace when creating the string instead of when outputting the string.

Demo:

```js
function whitespace(strings, ...keys) {
  return strings
    //keys[i] will be undefined in the last call
    .map((current, i) => current + (keys[i] || ''))
    .join('')
    //remove newlines, tabs, and replace multiple spaces with one space
    .replace(/\r?\n|\t| +(?= )/g, '');
}

var a = "a";
var b = "b";

// Basic, no change unless necessary 
console.log(whitespace`Test string: ${a}, ${b}`);

// Removes newlines
console.log(whitespace`Test
Newlines
Here
${a}`);

// Collapses multiple spaces
console.log(whitespace`Test      spaces`);
```